# When I use ng repeat to build selector and I am using options with same value

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

When I use ng repeat to build selector and I am using options with same value angulars returns 'Error: Duplicate md-option values are not allowed in a select. Duplicate value "1" found.'

```
angular.module('app',['ngMaterial'])
    .controller('repeatCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [
          { value: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
          { value: 1, name: 'Item 2' },
          { value: 1, name: 'Item 3' },
          { value: 4, name: 'Item 4' },
          { value: 5, name: 'Item 5' },
      ];
    });


<md-input-container>
    <label>choose item</label>
    <md-select ng-model="item">
        <md-option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</md-option>
    </md-select>
</md-input-container>
```

Comment: The error is very clear: don't duplicate values. It doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: I need to duplicate values :)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/7536

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, havent used material, but the below will work in regular angular and html.

```
<select ng-options="x as x.name for x in items" ng-model="item">
<option>Select something...</option></select>
```

and then use item.value where you need it